# Filter rule to move emails related to one person in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter

I have Outlook configured for mails and I want to create a rule such that matches where person "X" is either one of the following:

- Sender
- in the CC list
- in To list.

I need to move those emails into a specific folder.

How can I create this filter?

Comment: What version of Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Outlook handles the mentioned conditions as "AND" assignments I think you will need to define 3 rules to achieve this.

Comment: As i could not find a suitable way to do it, i created a VB Script and was able to do this and other things also.

Answer (score 1):

I use the "with text in the message header" rule, and add email addresses to it.